# How to skip to the last non-blank line?

Tags: navigation

Is there a way of calling `(end-of-buffer)` that excludes trailing empty lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can go to the end of the buffer, then move backwards over whitespace:

```
(progn (goto-char (point-max))
       (skip-chars-backward "\n[:space:]"))
```

If you want to call this interactively, make it into a command:

```
(defun end-of-buffer-before-whitespace ()
  "Move point to after the last non-whitespace character in the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (skip-chars-backward "\n[:space:]"))
```

Comment: Better use `"\n[:space:]"` instead of `"\n\t "` in `skip-chars-backward`.

Comment: Note, if you don't want the cursor to be at the line end, add `(move-beginning-of-line nil)`